# What is a cyclic group of prime order $q$ such that the DLP is hard?

Tags: hash, discrete-logarithm, group-theory, random-oracle-model

On the original paper on Linked Ring Signatures, in order to construct its scheme, the author relies on this:

> Let $G = \langle g\rangle$  be a cyclic group of prime order $q$ such that the underlying discrete logarithm problem (DLP) is hard. Let $H_1 : \{0, 1\}^∗ \to \mathbb Z_q$ and $H_2 : \{0, 1\}^∗ \to G$ be distinct hash functions viewed as random oracles.

What, specifically, is that group he mentions? Are there many ways to construct such a thing? If so, is there any that is easy to implement, yet hard to attack? Or am I looking for some kind of library? Moreover, how should one make such an $H_2$ that can be viewed as a random oracle?

Comment: They exist in the [Generic group model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_group_model).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Cyclic group of prime order *q* such that the DLP is hard

A simple technique to form a cyclic group $G$ of prime order $q$ such that the underlying discrete logarithm problem (DLP) is (conjecturally) hard, applicable to large $q$ (in the order of a thousand bits), is to pick $q$ as a random prime of appropriate size such that $p=2q+1$ is prime, and any integer $g$ with $1<g<p-1$ such that $g^q\bmod p=1$.

The $q$ elements of the cyclic group $G$ are $g^i\bmod p$ with $0\le i<q$, under modular multiplication modulo $p$.

The search of $q$ can be greatly sped up by using sieving techniques removing $q$ such that either $q$ or $2q+1$ is divisible by a small prime. To find $g$, we can pick a random $x\in[2,n-1)$ and compute $g=x^2$.

It is conjectured that the DLP is hard, that is: given $y=g^x\bmod p$ for unknown random $x$ in $\mathbb Z_q$, it is computationally infeasible to find $x$. The current public record for solving such problem is [for one instance of a 768-bit](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/067.pdf) $p$. Current recommendations for a decade of security are 2048 or 3072 bits, but 1024 bit is still widely used. Standard groups with $p$ of a slightly special form making modular reduction easier are given in [RFC 2409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409#section-6.2) and [RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526#page-3).

One way to obtain a speedup without sacrificing security (conjecturally) is to reduce the size of $q$, within some limit, with $q$ a divisor of $p-1$. That's a [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group). See [section 3.6.6](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap3.pdf#page=28) of Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone's [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), and their [algorithm 11.54](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap11.pdf#page=29). To find $g$, we can pick a random $x\in[1,n)$ and compute $g=x^r$, until $g\ne1$. Using a 256-bit $q$ for 2048-bit $p$ is believed to be about as safe as using a 2047-bit $q$, and recommendable. For now (2022), there is still no public attack with 160-bit $q$ and 1024-bit $p$, which used to be common. Execution time is about in proportion to the bit size of $q$, and roughly in proportion to the square of the bit size of $p$.

Slowness is a often concern! Common algorithms to compute $y=g^x\bmod p$ perform like $3(\log_2(p)/w)^2\log_2(x)$ multiplications of $w$-bit words and additions of the $2w$-bit result. For a software implementation using 32-bit words, 2048-bit $p$ and 2047-bit $x$, we are talking over 25 million muladds. Careful implementations using assembly language shine, including [the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/) (which has wrappers in interpreted languages, including [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2)). Also: be aware that side channel leakage, including by [timing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack), is a security concern depending heavily on the implementation of modular exponentiation.

There are other constructions using an [Elliptic Curve over a finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_finite_fields), giving another large speedup without sacrificing security (conjecturally); and yet other less common techniques. In the following I'll stick to a $G$ a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ of prime order $q$, with $p=r\cdot q+1$; and to $r=2$ (the simple technique discussed initially) unless otherwise noted.

---

### Construction of H<sub>1</sub>

What's wanted is a hash with output in $\mathbb Z_q$, (conjecturally) secure in the random oracle model (that is: computationally undistinguishable from a random function with the same input and output domain, knowing the definition of $H_1$ except some arbitrary constant part of that public definition).

The standard method for that is to use a hash to $\{0,1\}^k$, convert that to integer in $[0,2^k)$, and reduce it modulo $q$. When $k\ge\log_2q+128$, that has negligible bias.

For the hash, we have [SHA-3's SHAKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3#Instances) and other hashes with expandable output. Thus for 2047-bit $q$ we can use
$$H_1(\alpha)=\operatorname{SHAKE}(\alpha,2176)\bmod q$$

Earlier cryptographic hashes have limited width: the widest member of [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) is SHA-512, and a 2047-bit $q$ is nearly 4 times as wide. We can solve the size problem by concatenating several independent hashes, which we can obtain using [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Definition)-SHA-512 with different public arbitrary keys. With that method and $q$ of 2047 bits, we need $\lceil(2047+128)/512\rceil=5$ concatenated HMAC-SHA-512. For message $\alpha\in\{0, 1\}^*$ the hash could be
$$H_1(\alpha)=\big(\operatorname{HMAC}(\text{0x01},\alpha)\|\operatorname{HMAC}(\text{0x02},\alpha)\|\dots \|\operatorname{HMAC}(\text{0x05},\alpha)\big)\bmod q$$

Note: when using $q$ of up to 384 bits, which is fine if $p$ is still large enough, we won't need the complexity of concatenating multiple SHA-512 hashes.

---

### Construction of H<sub>2</sub>

What's wanted is a hash with output in the group $G$ constructed in the first section, (conjecturally) secure in the random oracle model. But there's a catch!

The quote in the question precisely matches section 3.1 of Joseph K. Liu and Duncan S. Wong's *Linkable ring signature: security models and new schemes*, in [proceedings of ICCSA 2005](https://doi.org//10.1007/11424826_65), which I located by asking [Google Books](https://books.google.com/) for *distinct hash functions viewed as random oracles*. Right after the question's quote is:

> Assume that for any $\alpha\in\{0, 1\}^*$, the discrete-log of $H_2(\alpha)$ to the base $g$ is intractable.

The reasonable way to interpret this additional requirement is that knowing the definition of $H_2$, and given $\alpha$, one should be computationally unable to find $x$ with $g^x=H_2(\alpha)$.

Adapting [Poncho's great suggestion](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39918) so that it works regardless of $r$, for 2048-bit $p$ we can use
$$H_2(\alpha)=\Big(\big((\operatorname{HMAC}(\text{0x11},\alpha)\|\dots\|\operatorname{HMAC}(\text{0x15},\alpha))\bmod(p-1)\big)+1\Big)^r\bmod p$$

This works by generating a random element $u$ of $\mathbb Z_p^*$, and computing $v=u^r\bmod p$. The result is in $\mathbb Z_q$, because $v^q\equiv{(u^r)}^q\equiv u^{rq}\equiv u^{p-1}\bmod p\equiv 1\pmod p$, with the last step using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). With $u$ essentially uniform on $\mathbb Z_p^*$, $v$ is essentially uniform on $G$.

I wish I had proof of my intuition that, for general $r$, solving  $g^x\bmod p=v$ for $x$ is hard including with knowledge of $u$; and that we could get away with generating $u$ in $\mathbb Z_q^*$ rather than in $\mathbb Z_p^*$. Poncho [proved](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/39903#comment91113_39918) both for $r=2$.

---

Words of caution: Many papers on ring signatures and e-voting that I have attempted to follow have lost me; I was often left wondering what exactly is assumed and proven about security, and what that means in practice. Some use a [bilinear pairing](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Ebosma/Students/MScThesis_DennisMeffert.pdf); while there are libraries for that, I advise to dive into this stuff only if all the math above has been striking one as evidence.

I'm sure that only a small fraction of the voting population can form an informed opinion on these topics. I conclude that using such methods for voting goes straight against a major goal: that voters trust the result.

Comment: Great answer. I understand it, yet it feels like a small slice of knowledge of a much broader field, of which not much I know. I've googled a Coursera on crypto and there is nothing of that stuff. So, what am I supposed to learn so that this answer becomes crystal clear? Should I pick a random book on crypto, number theory, algebra, or what? I'd highly appreciate if you could point me to the right direction. Cheers!

Comment: (Just a clarification, "under modular multiplication mod p" means `((((g * g) % p) * g) % p) * g...`, rather than `(g * g * g ... * g) % p`, right??)

Comment: @Viclib: You get the idea for "under modular multiplication modulo $p$". Notice the two expressions that you wrote yield the same result (assuming the first ends in `% p`and they have the same number of terms); and that there are shortcuts to drastically reduce the number of operations. My advise is to drop the paper that you are reading for a while, and work thru chapter 3 of the HAC, referring to chapter 2 when you find something that you do not yet know, and chapter 14 if you want to try making a computer implementation (but do not need resistance to attacks like side-channels). [edited]

Comment: Yep, I should've thought about it. I'm doing it now. Thanks, @fgrieu

Comment: A last request for advice: I need this system implemented in 2 weeks and there is no way in earth that I will understand all the proofs and theoretical background behind that work in that time. I have that kind of learning assigned for the long term and I loved that book because it gives the big picture concisely. Yet, do you think I can still implement that particular system by just asking precise definitions (like I did on this question) and passing to the code? Even if I don't really understand why, for example, under that technique you mention the DLP is conjecturally hard?

Comment: BTW: $g$ doesn't need to be random, if you can solve the DLog problem (or the cDH problem) for a nonrandom $g$, you can solve it for any $g$ of the same order.  Hence, if $g=2$ makes computation simpler, you can use that.

Comment: @Viclib: Admitting that the DLP is conjecturally hard with the construction that I give, or another classic one, won't harm or invalidate your work. But not understanding the requirements of a scheme that you implement is likely to result in something unsafe. Given the short timeframe, using a bigum package ([GMP](https://gmplib.org/)), or one [built in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or python, is a necessity for any implemnetation. [edited]

Comment: @fgrieu just letting you know that I guess my implementation works now, and that is mostly thank to you. I've ran many tests and all checks so far. But that is with the naive H2 version. I'm still having trouble finding a large group which works with the safe version of H2. The ones on RFC 2409 and RFC 3526 don't - I think because they don't respect $g^q \bmod p = 1$? Or maybe i'm missing something. Really tired now, I'll take a rest so tomorrow I see how I can get the right group. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @Viiclib: I do understand how you can get the equality that you asked [there](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/39984) standing; but I can't make sense of what checking the equality proves. I'll leave that to you. Just to understand: when you say "naive H2 version" is that the one with $H_2(\alpha)=g^{H(\alpha)}\bmod p$? Or one with a $p$ that you generate rather than a given? In the later case, my guess is that you got $p$ mixed up: the Oakley/MODP groups of RFC 2409 and RFC 3526 match all the necessary conditions; just check that you got $p$ right by checking $2^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1$.

Comment: @fgrieu the one with $H_2(a) = g^{H(a)}$. All my tests work with that one. As soon as I switch to any of the 2 safe versions presented here, all tests fail; which, I assumed, could only be because those generated values not on the groups I was using. Perhaps it could be something else, then... I will keep debugging. About the equality, I just wanted to know if they were equal to debug; indeed, that helped me to narrow down the problem and eventually fix many problems I detected on my implementation of the group operations. (Is there any way to check if a $x \in G$, so I can test $H_2$?)

Comment: @Viclib: you can test if $z\in G$ by checking $1\le z<p$ and $z^q\bmod p=1$. If the $H$ in $H_2(α) = g^{H(α)}$ is actually $H_1$, then $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not independent; that's not asked in that paper (witch employs "distinct"), but is required in this similar [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/027.pdf), which uses "statistically independent" (but removed the "discrete-log of $H_2(α)$ to the base $g$ is intractable" requirement present in both the later paper, and in yet a different form in that [earlier one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/027/20040217:035334).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/purescript-lrs) is the result of all this. Thank you very much.